# Calculating Average of a Column in R per other IDs in another column

Tags: r, average

I want to be able to calculate the average m.HR per day (or per cycle) for each turtle. I've tried figuring it out using summarize = but I only know how to use that to make one average overall.

Here's my code:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2015-05-23", "2015-05-24", "2015-05-25", 
"2015-05-26", "2015-05-27", "2015-05-28", "2015-05-29", "2015-05-30", 
"2015-05-31", "2015-06-01", "2015-06-02", "2015-06-03", "2015-06-04", 
"2015-06-05", "2015-06-06", "2015-06-07", "2015-06-08", "2015-06-09", 
"2015-06-10", "2015-06-16", "2015-06-17", "2015-06-18", "2015-06-19", 
"2015-06-20", "2015-06-21", "2015-06-22", "2015-06-23", "2015-06-24", 
"2015-06-25", "2015-06-26", "2015-06-27", "2015-07-02", "2015-07-03", 
"2015-07-04", "2015-07-05", "2015-07-06", "2015-07-07", "2015-07-08", 
"2015-07-09", "2015-07-10", "2015-07-11", "2015-07-12", "2015-07-16", 
"2015-07-17", "2015-07-18", "2015-07-19", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", 
"2015-07-22", "2015-07-23", "2015-07-24", "2015-07-25", "2015-07-26", 
"2015-07-29", "2015-07-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-01", "2015-08-02", 
"2015-08-03", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-05", "2015-08-06", "2015-08-07", 
"2015-08-08", "2015-08-09", "2015-09-18", "2015-09-19", "2015-09-20", 
"2015-09-21", "2015-09-22", "2015-09-23", "2015-09-24", "2015-09-25", 
"2015-09-26", "2015-09-27", "2015-09-28", "2015-09-29", "2015-09-30"
), class = "factor"), Turtle = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("R3L1", "R3L11", "R3L12", "R3L2", 
"R3L4", "R3L8", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1", "R8L4", "R8NAT123"), class = "factor"), 
    m.HR = c(7.56457, 6.66759, 17.51107, 9.72277, 19.44553, 13.07674, 
    28.115, 14.99467, 17.16947, 40.40479), Cycle = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

At the end, a new data frame should be made that shows the cycle, date, Turtle, and average m.HR per day.

Let me know if any questions, thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option that works without extra packages:

```
aggregate(m.HR ~ Turtle + Date + Cycle, YOUR_DATA, mean)
```

Returns:

```
  Turtle       Date Cycle     m.HR
1  R3L12 2015-05-23     1 17.46722
```

Comment: Great I like this way too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
df <- data %>%
  group_by(Turtle, Date) %>%
  summarize(Mean.HR = mean(m.HR))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package dplyr

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Date, Turtle) %>%
  summarise(mean_m.HR = mean(m.HR))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(mean_m.HR = mean(m.HR, na.rm = TRUE)), .(Date, Turtle)]
```